# Scroll snapping not working with Tailwind CSS and Vue.js/Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to implement scroll snapping for my hero sections using Tailwind CSS in a Vue.js project. However, even after setting the necessary CSS properties for scroll snapping, it doesn't seem to work.

Here's the relevant CSS from my `tailwind.css`:

```css
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css";

body {
    @apply overflow-x-hidden;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    height: 100vh; /* Tried adding this */
    overflow-y: scroll; /* Tried adding this */
}

.hero-snap-section {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

And the relevant Vue template from `index.vue`:

```js
<template>
    <!-- Main Content -->
    <main class="container p-4 mx-auto">
        <!-- First Hero Section -->
        <div class="container flex flex-col items-center gap-4 px-4 pt-4 mx-auto mt-4 md:grid md:grid-cols-6 lg:grid-cols-12 md:px-8 hero-snap-section">
            <!-- ... other content ... -->
        </div>
        <!-- ... other sections ... -->
    </main>
</template>
```

I've ensured that the `hero-snap-section` class is applied to the sections I want to snap to. However, when I scroll, the sections don't snap as expected.

Any ideas on what might be causing this or how to fix it?

---

I've tried adding `height: 100vh;` and `overflow-y: scroll;` to my `body` but nothing changed.

I tested on Chrome and Edge.

Full ish code snippet

```js
<template>
    <!-- Main Content -->
    <main class="container p-4 mx-auto">
    
        <!-- First Hero Section -->
        <div class="container flex flex-col items-center gap-4 px-4 pt-4 mx-auto mt-4 md:grid md:grid-cols-6 lg:grid-cols-12 md:px-8 hero-snap-section">
            <!-- ... other content ... -->
        </div>
    
        <!-- Second Hero Section -->
        <section>
            <div
        class="container flex flex-col items-center gap-4 px-4 pt-4 mx-auto mt-4 md:flex-row md:grid md:grid-cols-6 lg:grid-cols-12 md:px-8 hero-snap-section">
            </div>
        </section>
    
         <!-- Third Hero Section -->
        <div class="container flex flex-col items-center gap-4 px-4 pt-4 mx-auto mt-4 md:grid md:grid-cols-6 lg:grid-cols-12 md:px-8 hero-snap-section">
            <!-- ... other content ... -->
        </div>
    
        <!-- Foruth Hero Section -->
        <section>
            <div
        class="container flex flex-col items-center gap-4 px-4 pt-4 mx-auto mt-4 md:flex-row md:grid md:grid-cols-6 lg:grid-cols-12 md:px-8 hero-snap-section">
            </div>
        </section>
    
    </main>
</template>
```

```css
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.hero-snap-section {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    height: 100vh;
    border: 1px solid red; /* For visualization */
}
```

```html
<!-- Main Content -->
<main class="container p-4 mx-auto">
    <!-- First Hero Section -->
    <div class="hero-snap-section">
        <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dwgnjyezw/image/upload/e_improve,w_500,h_500,c_thumb,g_auto/v1693301320/samples/animals/three-dogs.jpg" alt="Banner Image">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus lacinia odio vitae vestibulum.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Second Hero Section -->
    <div class="hero-snap-section">
        <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dwgnjyezw/image/upload/e_improve,w_500,h_500,c_thumb,g_auto/v1693301320/samples/animals/three-dogs.jpg" alt="Banner Image">
        <p>Donec sit amet nisl. Aliquam semper ipsum sit amet velit. Suspendisse id sem consectetuer libero luctus adipiscing.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- ... Repeat for other sections ... -->
</main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need the `scroll-snap-type` on the scrolling parent of the sections you'd want scroll snapping behavior for. In this case, it could be the `<main>` element:

```css
main {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    height: 100vh; /* Tried adding this */
    overflow-y: scroll; /* Tried adding this */
}

.hero-snap-section {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<!-- Main Content -->
<main class="container p-4 mx-auto">

  <!-- First Hero Section -->
  <div class="container flex flex-col items-center gap-4 px-4 pt-4 mx-auto mt-4 md:grid md:grid-cols-6 lg:grid-cols-12 md:px-8 hero-snap-section bg-red-200">
    <!-- ... other content ... -->
  </div>

  <!-- Second Hero Section -->
  <section>
    <div class="container flex flex-col items-center gap-4 px-4 pt-4 mx-auto mt-4 md:flex-row md:grid md:grid-cols-6 lg:grid-cols-12 md:px-8 hero-snap-section bg-blue-200">
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Third Hero Section -->
  <div class="container flex flex-col items-center gap-4 px-4 pt-4 mx-auto mt-4 md:grid md:grid-cols-6 lg:grid-cols-12 md:px-8 hero-snap-section bg-green-200">
    <!-- ... other content ... -->
  </div>

  <!-- Foruth Hero Section -->
  <section>
    <div class="container flex flex-col items-center gap-4 px-4 pt-4 mx-auto mt-4 md:flex-row md:grid md:grid-cols-6 lg:grid-cols-12 md:px-8 hero-snap-section bg-yellow-200">
    </div>
  </section>

</main>
```

Comment: This works, however it creates a new scroll bar for me because I have a template which puts main as a content between the header and footer, where the header is in a fixed position. But I'm guessing this will be another problem for me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JoeyLeo if this answer solved your issue then consider selecting it as the correct answer by clicking on the check mark button